# Automake variables resolution

Tags: automake

I am a newbie and I am trying to learn from sourcecodes. Now I have problem understanding (for learn!) autotools: here I have some variables. In this following variable declaration-assignment

```
mousepad_CFLAGS = \
    $(GLIB_CFLAGS) \
    $(GTK_CFLAGS) \
    $(GTHREAD_CFLAGS) \
    $(GTKSOURCEVIEW_CFLAGS) \
    $(PLATFORM_CFLAGS) \
    -DMOUSEPAD_GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=\""$(datadir)/glib-2.0/schemas"\"
```

The variables GLIB_CFLAGS GTK_CFLAGS GTHREAD_CFLAGS GTKSOURCEVIEW_CFLAGS PLATFORM_CFLAGS were not declared. From where their origins?

Also at the bottom there is another undeclared variable reference:

```
@GSETTINGS_RULES@
```

Answer (score 0):

Those variables are defined by the `configure` script when it is run (depending on what `configure` found and where) and then those variable definitions are inserted into the `Makefile` generated from `Makefile.in`.